# Fixing a hardwood floor mistake

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor

Following a YouTube video, I tried to minimize some scratches in a hardwood floor (installed by previous owner) with Weiman Wood Floor Polish and Restorer, and instead made them look worse. See photo. How can I undo this? Thanks!
[image: discolored hardwood floor]

Answer (score 1):

The only issue I can see is that the scuffs lack the sheen of the original finish. I'd try a wax or other polish to try and get some of that shine back. That might be all it takes.